# network-manager forgot wifi password when on another machine

Tags: networkmanager

I just moved my drive to a new computer, and network manager completely forgot the password of all my wifi connections, even.if I can still find them listed in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` with the password in KWallet.

I guess that the issue is that the name of the wifi interface is different, what is the clean way to reuse these passwords on this new wifi interface?